# how does mongo determine how to serialize an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm working with a `BigNumber`s from the [bignumber.js package](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/blob/master/bignumber.d.ts)

I'm new to Mongo and I'm curious as to how Mongo knows how to serialize this object correctly (or any other object for that matter)?

I ask because I have 2 scripts which are seemingly identical in they way the insert these objects, but in one script the `BigNumber`s are inserted as strings in the other script they are inserted as numbers.

The object comes in from an `any` stream and I need to convert or cast the any object to `Altitude`.

Sample code:

```
export interface Altitude {
    altitude: BigNumber;
    minAltitude: BigNumber;
    maxAltitude: BigNumber;
}

... 'message' object of type any from stream ...
// this JSON back and forth stuff seems like it should be unnecessary
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(message);
let alt = JSON.parse(jsonString) as Altitude;    

collection.insert(alt, (error: MongoError, result: InsertOneWriteOpResult) => {
    ...
});
```

Strings are inserted for the `BigNumber`s.

Seeing the values being inserted into Mongo as strings I try forcing the issue even more, just to see if it would work:

```
let alt = JSON.parse(jsonString) as Altitude;
let alt1 = {
    size: alt.altitude as BigNumber,
    minAltitude: alt.minAltitude as BigNumber,
    maxAltitude: alt.minAltitude as BigNumber,
};

collection.insert(alt1, (error: MongoError, result: InsertOneWriteOpResult) => {
    ...
});
```

However the values are still inserted as strings. And in my other script everything is numbers.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) Serialisation. The actual implementation would depend on the driver.

Reference https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson